# pytest parametrised fixture with different cases

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have several test cases and test functions, and the list of test cases is different for the different functions. This can be easily done with `pytest.mark.parametrize`. The extra need I have is to load a resource (a file in my case) and I'd like to have this file only loaded once per test session and cached.

Below an example illustrating what I want. It's working, but I would like to find a way to use pytest fixtures or some other caching mechanism so that I don't have to do the caching myself and have the `pars=load_file(pars)` line in each test function.

Can someone please explain how to do this with pytest?

```
import pytest

case_1 = dict(label='case_1', spam=1)
case_2 = dict(label='case_2', spam=2)
case_3 = dict(label='case_3', spam=3)

_cache = {}


def load_file(pars):
    if pars['label'] in _cache:
        print('load_file from cache', pars)
        return _cache[pars['label']]
    else:
        print('load_file loading', pars)
        pars['file'] = pars['label'] + ' spam!'
        _cache[pars['label']] = pars
        return pars


@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', [case_1, case_2])
def test_a(pars):
    pars = load_file(pars)
    print('test_a', pars)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', [case_2, case_3])
def test_b(pars):
    pars = load_file(pars)
    print('test_b', pars)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', [case1, case_2, case_3])
def test_c(pars):
    pars = load_file(pars)
    print('test_c', pars)

### more tests here for various combinations of test cases
```

Answer (score 1):

The first and the obvious solution is to use the session-scoped fixtures. However, it requires restructuring the test file, and load all of the known files in advance.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def pars_all():
   cache = {}
   for case in [case_1, case_2, case_3]:
       cache[case['label']] = 'case {} content'.format(case)

   yield cache

   # optionally destroy or unload or unlock here.

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def pars(request, pars_all):
    label = request.param
    yield pars_all[label]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', ['case_1', 'case_2'], indirect=True)
def test(pars):
    pass
```

Please note the indirect parametrisation. It means that the `pars` fixture will be prepared instead, getting a parameter value in `request.param`. The parameter name and the fixture must share the same name.

The session-scoped fixture (or module-scoped, or class-scoped if you wish) will be prepared only once for all the tests. It is important to note that the wider-scoped fixtures can be used in the more narrow-scoped or same-scoped fixtures, but not in the opposite direction.

If the cases are not that well-defined, it is the same easy, just the cache is populated on demand:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def pars_all():
    yield {}

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def pars(request, pars_all):
    label = request.param
    if label not in pars_all:
        print('[[[{}]]]'.format(request.param))
        pars_all[label] = 'content of {}'.format(label)
    yield pars_all[label]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', ['case_1', 'case_2'], indirect=True)
def test_1(pars):
    print(pars)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('pars', ['case_1', 'case_3'], indirect=True)
def test_2(pars):
    print(pars)
```

Note, that the `{}` object is created only once, because it is session-scoped, and is shared among all tests & callspecs. So, if one fixture adds something into it, other fixtures will see it too. You can notice that on how `case_1` is reused in the `test_2`:

```
$ pytest -s -v -ra test_me.py 
======= test session starts ==========
...
collected 4 items                                                                                   

test_me.py::test_1[case_1] [[[case_1]]]
content of case_1
PASSED
test_me.py::test_1[case_2] [[[case_2]]]
content of case_2
PASSED
test_me.py::test_2[case_1] content of case_1
PASSED
test_me.py::test_2[case_3] [[[case_3]]]
content of case_3
PASSED

======== 4 passed in 0.01 seconds ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple use of [`@lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) in your file parsing function can also do the caching trick:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=3)
def load_file(file_name):
    """ This function loads the file and returns contents"""
    print("loading file " + file_name)
    return "<dummy content for " + file_name + ">"
```

You can also reach the same result while making the whole code a bit more readable by separating the test functions from the test cases with [pytest-cases](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) (I'm the author by the way!):

```
from functools import lru_cache
from pytest_cases import parametrize_with_cases

@lru_cache(maxsize=3)
def load_file(file_name):
    """ This function loads the file and returns contents"""
    print("loading file " + file_name)
    return "<dummy content for " + file_name + ">"

def case_1():
    return load_file('file1')

def case_2():
    return load_file('file2')

def case_3():
    return load_file('file3')

@parametrize_with_cases("pars", cases=[case_1, case_2])
def test_a(pars):
    print('test_a', pars)

@parametrize_with_cases("pars", cases=[case_2, case_3])
def test_b(pars):
    print('test_b', pars)

@parametrize_with_cases("pars", cases=[case_1, case_2, case_3])
def test_c(pars):
    print('test_c', pars)
```

Yields:

```
loading file file1
test_a <dummy content for file1>PASSED
loading file file2
test_a <dummy content for file2>PASSED
test_b <dummy content for file2>PASSED
loading file file3
test_b <dummy content for file3>PASSED
test_c <dummy content for file1>PASSED
test_c <dummy content for file2>PASSED
test_c <dummy content for file3>PASSED
```

Finally note that depending on your use case you might wish to switch to a [case generator](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/#case-generators) by using `@parametrize` on a case function, that could be more readable:

```
from pytest_cases import parametrize

@parametrize("file_name", ["file1", "file2"])
def case_gen(file_name):
    return load_file(file_name)
```

Also look at [tags & filters](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/#filters-and-tags), if you do not want to hardcode the cases explicitly.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: This might be one of the most useful answer I've read since I joined SO, thank you very much for that! Is there any way to tell `@parameterize` what test to generate cases for ? I have loads of duplicate versions of your last code sample in `<test case>_cases.py` files and I can't seem to find a way to get rid of that duplicate code...

Comment: Hi @ssc thanks so much for this nice comment ! The best for this kind of discussion would be to open an issue at https://github.com/smarie/python-pytest-cases/issues explaining your need and what you tried so far in more details. See you there !